# java DecimalFormat vs localization and not internationalization

Tags: java, localization, internationalization

At https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat#DecimalFormat() the documentation for the DecimalFormat constructor says:

*Creates a DecimalFormat using the default pattern and symbols for the default FORMAT locale. This is a convenient way to obtain a DecimalFormat when internationalization is not the main concern.*

Since localization is part of internationalization, and this constructor uses the current/default locale (i.e. it localizes), what issue is this text trying to call attention to, i.e. what is this sentence saying this method **does NOT** do?

Answer (score 1):

This method doesn't alloy you to specify locale.

Imagine that you have multi language interface. It allows user to choose language. You can't use this method because it will use default locale, not locale specified by user.

You may use `NumberFormat.getInstance(loc)` to specify locale.

Comment: So it does localize and hence support internationalization, but just does not support using a different/custom locale than the default/active one.